# Get last part of string with multiple preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

Spotify has two ways to use url's/identifiers. I want to get the last part of the strings below (the ID)

```
example url's:
a. https://play.spotify.com/artist/6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao
b. spotify:artist:6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao
```

Can't get the code below to work, so I can add more options to it later as well. I tried basename first, but obviously that doesn't work with ':'.

```
$str = "https://play.spotify.com/artist/6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao";
or:
$str = "spotify:artist:6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao";

if (
    preg_match('artist/([a-zA-Z0-9]{22})/', $str, $re) ||
    preg_match('artist:([a-zA-Z0-9]{22})/', $str, $re)

) {
  $spotifyId = $re[1];
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are the ID's always the same length?

Comment: I think so. Couldn't find it in any documentation of Spotify. Edit: I found this: The base-62 identifier that you can find at the end of the Spotify URI (see above) for an artist, track, album, playlist, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for urls having slashes. If the Spotify string uses colons(`:`) simply switch the `/` to a `:` in the `explode()` function:

```
// your url
$url = "https://play.spotify.com/artist/6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao/blah/blah/blah";

// get path only
$path = parse_url($url)['path'];

// seperate by forward slash
$parts = explode('/', $path);

// go through them and find string with 22 characters
$id = '';
foreach ($parts as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($value) === 22 ) {
        // found it, now store it
        $id = $value;
        break;
    }
}
```

A rough sample of a helpful function would be as follows:

```
function getSpotifyId($spotifyUrl) {
    // check for valid url
    if (!filter_var($spotifyUrl, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        // split using colon
        $parts = explode(':', parse_url($spotifyUrl)['path']);
    } elseif (filter_var($spotifyUrl, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        // split using forward slash
        $parts = explode('/', parse_url($spotifyUrl)['path']);
    }

    // loop through segments to find id of 22 chars
    foreach ($parts as $key => $value) {
        // assuming id will always be 22 characters
        if (strlen($value) === 22 ) {
            // found it, now return it
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$id1 = getSpotifyId('http://localhost/xampp/web_development/6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao/stack.php');
$id2 = getSpotifyId('spotify:artist:6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao');
$id3 = getSpotifyId('My name is tom');
```

results:

`$id1 = '6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao'`

`$id2 = '6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao'`

`$id3 = false`

Comment: Clever! But what if there is more after the code? Like a slash and more data? That is why I want to get the ID behind the : or /

Comment: @KJS provide and example so I can see what you mean, please.

Comment: That would be something like: https://play.spotify.com/artist/6mdiAmATAx73kdxrNrnlao/extra-url-seo-nonsense